# Web application in a network environment

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04, localhost, hostname

I have a web application running on an apache web server on Ubuntu 10.04. The web application can be accessed via a web browser on the server's computer by typing **http://localhost/webapp**.

I want to make this application available in a networking environment. So I first set a unique IP address for the server and every computer connected to the server could only access the login page of the web application. I get a certain error whenever a user tries to access another page expect the login page. 
**ERROR: The web page cannot be accessed with the address localhost**

So I want every page of the web application to be accessible to every computer in the network.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the word *localhost* to the server's IP address (or DNS name if you have one setup), it's that simple. The term localhost is what a single server can, if needed, call just itself, a bit like the term 'me' in your inner monologue.

Comment: I especially liked your "inner monologue" point.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure the IP address you are using is correct.

```
http://your_server_ip/webapp
```

Then, you need to make sure that the code inside webapp does not refer to the other web pages using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.